# I am trying to make a jQuery modal popup dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make a jQuery hover modal popup window for my new project (not tooltip.) Unfortunately it is not working.

Please check this Codepen link https://codepen.io/coderco/pen/MWGgqop. I am looking for same working as this with jQuery.

https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/bartek-malanowski/226737

Here is my codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".test" ).hover(function() { //Hover Function
           $('.modal').modal({ // Modal
        show: true
    });
  });  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="test">Jquery Hover Modal Popup</button>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
Jquery Hover Modal Popup
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included jquery-ui?   Please create a full snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:jquery-ui] but the [jquery-ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) code is `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();`.   You've used `$(".modal").modal(...` and the classname `bs-example-modal-sm` also indicates that you're trying to create a [tag:bootstrap-modal].  Please clarify.

Comment: Please refrain from making hostile rollbacks - the new version is much more readable, and contains far less fluff.

Answer (score 0):

Here in html firstly I removed the extra `script` tag I added a new attribute `hidden="true"` to hide the model and in jquery used built in function.

The popup will get hidden when someone will hoverout.

```js
$(".test").hover(function() {
  $('.modal').show();
}, function() {
  $('.modal').hide();
});
```

```css
.modal { margin:0.5em 0; padding: 0.5em; border:1px solid rebeccapurple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="test">Jquery Hover Modal Popup</button>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Jquery Hover Modal Popup
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi.. you made it as tooltip  .. I am looking for Modal Popup. Not tooltip.

Comment: You probably mean a modal *dialog*.

Comment: Yes. Modal dialogue when hover

Comment: You asked for popup. I thought you are lacking the logic my bad.

Comment: I am looking for same as this https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/bartek-malanowski/226737 with Jquery.